# How can I set a <div> to the width of the browser window on page load (i.e. so it stays the same width when the browser window is resized)

Tags: css, html, width

When I set a width of a `<div>` that wraps all page by 100%, whenever I resize the window the `<div>` resizes as well.

What I want to achieve is, for whatever browser and screen you open the page, I want the div to have the widh of the 100% of the full window and **stay it as it was set**, so that when you resize the window, the div size will still be the same.

Is it possible?

Comment: I wonder why this can not be achieved by CSS, though. Such a solution can mislead a developer or a designer.

Comment: Is the DIV absolutely positioned?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using jQuery as:

```
winW = $(window).width();

$('#container').css('width', winW);
```

Comment: Why are you setting the height as well?

Comment: You should get the width (and height) of the specific `div`, not of the whole window.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the width to be 100% in your css, and then use a JavaScript onLoad function to override it to pixels. Your users should not notice it.

You can find many examples of the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `onload` to retrieve the calculated width after loading, then set it as the `div`'s defined width:

```
$(function() {
    var width = $("#mydiv").width();
    $("#mydiv").width(width);
});
```